# VS 2010 error "Value to add was out of range. Parameter name: value "

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am facing a weird problem. My web application throws error "Value to add was out of range Parameter name :value ". Now this is not every time I run the program.Sometimes shows error and sometimes runs without problems (no changes done).stack traces given below the error is not clear (at least for me). Anybody faced this kind of issue ?

## Error Details

Value to add was out of range.
Parameter name: value 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Value to add was out of range.
Parameter name: value

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Value to add was out of range.
Parameter name: value]
   System.DateTime.Add(Double value, Int32 scale) +9388319
   System.Web.Compilation.CodeDirectoryCompiler.GetCodeDirectoryAssembly(VirtualPath virtualDir, CodeDirectoryType dirType, String assemblyName, StringSet excludedSubdirectories, Boolean isDirectoryAllowed) +8837703
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileCodeDirectory(VirtualPath virtualDir, CodeDirectoryType dirType, String assemblyName, StringSet excludedSubdirectories) +125
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileCodeDirectories() +319
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +248

[HttpException (0x80004005): Value to add was out of range.
Parameter name: value]
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ReportTopLevelCompilationException() +62
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +421
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallAppInitializeMethod() +31
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +605

[HttpException (0x80004005): Value to add was out of range.
Parameter name: value]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9013676
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +97
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr) +258




--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1
```

[image]

Comment: Could you copy-paste the error text in the post?

Comment: Its crashing at the line `DateTime.Add()` where are you using this in your code? Post that too

Comment: @Michael Sagalovich : Thought screenshot will be more detailed. Anywayz plz see the details below :

Comment: @giddy : I am not using the statement anywhere in my code. Even did a quick search in the solution and no such line.I tried running the project in another PC and it works fine there.

Comment: @Michael Sagalovich : edited the original post with the error text .

Comment: @mkkvs - Make sure the value of 'value' after the value of 'scale' is applied to it is within the max and min values of a DateTime.

Comment: Guys, see the trace, it is not in the OP's code, it is somewhere inside `System.Web.Compilation`, where the faulty method gets called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just guesses: as the exception seems to be thrown from the code that you do not control, it is not your code that causes the error. However, that could be your system settings. For example, for some weird reason `System.DateTime.Add(Double value, Int32 scale)` is called with such parameters, that, as [MSDN states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.add.aspx),

> The resulting DateTime is less than MinValue or greater than MaxValue.

Is it ever possible that the time on your computer is now set to some incredibly high value? Close to `23:59:59.9999999, December 31, 9999`, for instance. Or maybe low value, close to `00:00:00.0000000, January 1, 0001`. So the compiler for some reasons picks up the current date and needs to add some time span to it, which causes your error.

Just a wild guess, but maybe...

**UPDATE**

The code of the `System.Web.Compilation.CodeDirectoryCompiler.GetCodeDirectoryAssembly` method can be found [here](http://www.wikiencyclopedia.net/net/DotNET/DotNET/8.0/untmp/whidbey/REDBITS/ndp/fx/src/xsp/System/Web/Compilation/CodeDirectoryCompiler.cs/2/CodeDirectoryCompiler.cs). In the code there is a line

```
DateTime waitLimit = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMilliseconds(3000);
```

That's the only place that could throw such exception (if the version I am looking at is the same as your environment). So it gives more votes for weird time set on your computer.

Comment: True the error might be thrown by my system settings but I checked my date time settings and everything seems to be fine. Do you think the reason may be a corrupt installation ? The code works fine on my other configuration (Vista 32bit - VS professional 2010) but on Win 7 32 bit -VS professional 2010 it fails

Comment: I'd start with writing a small console app that does exactly the same: `DateTime waitLimit = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMilliseconds(3000)` somewhere inside `Main` to see what happens, what is `DateTime.UtcNow`, for instance. That may give a clue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.The issue is solved as of now. Will try to investigate if it occurs again.:)

Answer (score 2):

This can happen if the value you are trying to assign is `null`. Try coalescing the value

suppose:

```
int i = value ?? 0; //if value is null, zero is assigned to i
MyClass _class = ValueClass ?? new MyClass(); //same as above, except it instantiates.
DateTime someDate = getChuckNorrisBirthDate() ?? DateTime.Now.Date(); // beware of chuck norris
```

<sub>I have seen this error with `DateTime` variables.. but it was ages ago. Since you do not provide enough information about the type of variable etc (and the image is too small to make out anything) I am just guessing it on top of my head.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved. Just changed my regional settings,date/time settings in control panel to some random setting and then reverted them back to original followed by a PC restart and error is gone.Issue might be with the GetCodeDirectoryAssembly code as mentioned by @Michael Sagalovich.Will investigate for more details if the error pops up again :)

Thanks All